# Pull data from different APIs

Tags: java, android, json, api

I have created a news app and I wanted to pull articles from the different APIs via newsapi.org that would show up in different activities. I created

So for example, Techcrunch and Reuters. I have similar code for each activity but i switched the API link since it needs to pull from either TechCrunch and Reuters individually. Instead, only one of the activities work and the other is blank.

If i place the same API link in both activities, it works flawlessly. Please help

```
private  void parseJSON () {
    String url = "http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=*";

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {


        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray =response.getJSONArray("articles");

                for (int i = 0; i< jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject article = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String authorName = article.getString("author");
                    String imageUrl = article.getString("urlToImage");
                    String published = article.getString("publishedAt");
                    String description = article.getString("content");
                    String headline = article.getString("title");

                    mNewsList.add(new newsItem(imageUrl, authorName, published,description, headline ));

                }
```

Comment: Maybe the other link is not returning data, debug your code and check if response actually has data

Comment: @y.allam both links return data if i attempt one activity but problems arise when i try 2 pull activities

Comment: what do you mean by "try 2 pull activities"? please share more code if you can

Comment: Sorry. I use the same code for the two activities with just the API URL changing. It only pulls data from one API URL. If I use the exact URL for both activities it will work fine. If I switch it, it only pulls from one URL and otber activity is blank. Wish i could share screen

Comment: If the URL is the ONLY thing different, so clearly the issue is in the URL, or the data it returns

Answer (score 0):

To get articles from a particular source use this URL :

[https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=abc-news&apiKey="yourkey"](https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=abc-news&apiKey=%22yourkey%22)

Comment: that is not the issue

Answer (score 0):

In you blank activity, do some break points and check network call returns success data or error. If network data success, then check your json parsing code to see it parses correctly.

You may try network logging interceptor to see what things are happening to your HTTP network calls.